# My Server returning 302 for site root how can i make the my domain without redirect to default.aspx?

Tags: iis-6

when i enter http://www.spotagel.com and hit enter it does redirect to http://www.spotagel.com/default.aspx , and with 302 response, how sould i change my dns records to point to root without redirection?
a tool redirect-check returns 302 found ,

i tried everything , at last i assume my dns configuration is wrong some way.

i am using bind dns on windows 2003 web server

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your DNS.  The domain name is resolving to the right thing.  Your web server is generating the 302 redirect, because while the visitor asks for / they are being redirected to the default index page with a 302.

302's aren't a problem unless you're experiencing an actual issue.

Google returns a 302 redirect for example,

```
wget -S http://www.google.com
--2011-08-16 21:30:39--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com... 74.125.113.147, 74.125.113.99, 74.125.113.103, ...
Connecting to www.google.com|74.125.113.147|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.0 302 Found
  Location: http://www.google.fr/
  Cache-Control: private
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Date: Tue, 16 Aug 2011 20:32:01 GMT
  Server: gws
  Content-Length: 218
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  Connection: Keep-Alive
```

In summary - you need to look at IIS.

Comment: but in my case a redirection occurs to default.aspx and redirection code is 302

Comment: Yes I know, your IIS web server is creating the redirect.  There is never a document actually at www.example.com/ - there's always a filename needed, in some cases it's a redirect to the default index page (index.html for example) achieved via a 302.  This is normal - so what is the exact *problem* you are trying to fix.  Browsers will follow the 302 redirect and get the default.aspx page.

Comment: i want to url stay what it is typed as, spotagel.com, occurs spotagel.com/default.aspx on address bar

Comment: Then you need to look at your IIS config, it's nothing to do with DNS.

Comment: i have used some redirection methods to site root that casuing infinite loops